# Swift: Make UISegmentedView uneditable

Tags: ios, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

Pretty self explanatory title: quickly make a UISegmentedView uneditable. This means the user will not be able to change the selected segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the interaction of `segmentdControl` try like this.

```
self.segmentedControl.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using userInterractionEnable = false to set all kind of UIView UIControl interaction.